# Find all the pages for which a user is an admin using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Until now, I was using FQL. I've seen that it's going to be removed (when, I don't know).

When I have obtained the rights to query the user profile, I can find out the pages she manages. Something like the following example. So from page_admin, I get the details of all the pages.

`$fql = "select talking_about_count, access_token, description, emails,fan_count,general_info, location, page_url, pic_square, username, page_id,name from page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_admin where uid = ".$user['fbuid'].')';`

`$fql = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user['fbuid'].'/fql?access_token='.$user['token'].'&q='.urlencode($fql);`

I cannot find the equivalent using the graph API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[/me/accounts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/accounts) with the `manage_pages` permission is what you need

Comment: As simple as that ! Thank you.